# My chrome inspection doesn't recognize my vs code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[enter image description here][1] - Here are the images.

[[1]: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oRD5oNZOBs0/Xpx3MTxKs4I/AAAAAAAAA6c/YsbiZar_8Ks_Mbe-b7XpgLpeqZDlrfqJwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-04-19.png][1]

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5MQ3CPS5I3I/Xpx3Pbf81vI/AAAAAAAAA6g/T_tmnoMdhmYg_MUbQgArA7pcq7muAcsAwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-04-19.png

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KYzb4Eeyapo/Xpx3R7UeZjI/AAAAAAAAA6k/HOZR9KJMA74pljh77pj9N6WV0wmuYD-PwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-04-19.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't saved your file in VS Code. Do `CTRL + S` and try again

Comment: Thanks a lot Naseh, u helped me